# AsyncIO Exception in FastAPI WebSocket

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

I see below exception for the given code.After starting FastAPi first time it works perfectly and then throws the exception and further requests only writes to stream but not continuous processing happens.I am sharing both the code and the exception.I am building a realtime asr websocket using azure speech sdk.

```
# Create a speech config
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=AZURE_SPEECH_KEY, region=AZURE_SPEECH_REGION)
# auto_detect_source_language_config = \
#     speechsdk.languageconfig.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(languages=["en-US", "ae-AR"])
speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"  # Set the language
audio_format = AudioStreamFormat(
        # channels=1,
        samples_per_second=16000,
        bits_per_sample=16
    )
stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(audio_format)

speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config,
                                               audio_config=speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream))
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=AZURE_SPEECH_KEY, region=AZURE_SPEECH_REGION)
speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"  # Set the language
audio_format = AudioStreamFormat(samples_per_second=16000, bits_per_sample=16)
stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(audio_format)
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config,
                                               audio_config=speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream))



queue = []

done=asyncio.Event()

stream_lock = asyncio.Lock()
recognizing_alive,recognized_alive=datetime.datetime.now(),datetime.datetime.now()

def recognized_callback(evt):
    recognized_text = evt.result.text
    queue.append(recognized_text)
    global recognized_alive
    recognized_alive = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Recognized ALive" + str(recognized_alive))


def recognizing_callback(evt):
    global recognizing_alive
    recognizing_alive=datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Recognizing ALive"+str(recognizing_alive))

speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_callback)
speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(recognizing_callback)

async def validate_stream_processed():
    while True:
        global recognizing_alive
        global recognized_alive
        diff=(datetime.datetime.now()-recognized_alive).total_seconds()
        print("The diff is "+str(diff))
        if diff>10:
            print("I am breaking of validate stream process")
            done.set()
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
async def read_queue(websocket):
    print("About to read")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if queue:
            async with stream_lock:
                if queue:
                    item = queue.pop(0)
                    print("About to send: ", item)
                    await websocket.send_text(item)

        if done.is_set():
            break

async def write_stream(stream,data):

    # The number of bytes to push per buffer
    n_bytes = 4096
    data = io.BytesIO(data)
    try:
        while True:
            frames = data.read(n_bytes // 2)
            print('read {} bytes'.format(len(frames)))
            if not frames:
                print("I am breaking from read stream")
                break

            async with stream_lock:
                stream.write(frames)
                print("Wrote one")
            print("Entring Wait in write")
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            print("Cameout in write")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

async def write_stream_and_process(speech_recognizer, stream, data):
    await write_stream(stream, data)
    # After writing to the stream, start continuous recognition


@app.websocket("/asr/en")
async def root(websocket: WebSocket):
    global speech_recognizer
    global stream
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
        # speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(write_stream_and_process(speech_recognizer, stream, data))
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(read_queue(websocket))
        task3 = asyncio.create_task(validate_stream_processed())
        await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, task3)

    except asyncio.CancelledError:

        print("WebSocket task cancelled")

    except Exception as e:

        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:

        global queue
        print("Closing WebSocket Connection")
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        print("Stopped Recognition")
        stream.close()
        print("Clearing Queue")
        queue.clear()
        print("Items in Queue at Finish", queue)
        print("Stream closed")
        await websocket.close()
```

```
   Exception in callback StreamReaderProtocol.connection_made.<locals>.callback(<Task cancell...erver.py:102>>) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py:248
handle: <Handle StreamReaderProtocol.connection_made.<locals>.callback(<Task cancell...erver.py:102>>) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py:248>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py", line 249, in callback
    exc = task.exception()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 105, in handler
    await handle_http(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/_handlers/http.py", line 80, in handle_http
    data = await reader_read
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py", line 708, in read
    await self._wait_for_data('read')
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py", line 540, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```